# Calabash-Android IF ELSE

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash

I'm currently writing test scripts for my Android application using calabash-android. One problem I'm facing is that I don't always know the route the application should go down.

For example, if I open a job that job could throw a warning to confirm you want to open the job before the next "job" activity is shown, however other jobs might not show this warning.

What I need is a way to analyse a particular view with an if/else statement in my cucumber code. Has anyone managed to achieve this previously?

Below is an example of what I'm after:

```
Scenario: As a valid user I can log into my app and view my jobs list
When I see "Log In"
Then I enter text "JoeBloggs" into field with id "txtUsername"
Then I enter text "Password123" into field with id "txtPassword"
Then I press "Log In"
And I wait
Then I see "Welcome To The Your Application"
Then I press "Jobs"
And I wait
Then I see "Back"
Then I see "Job Number"
Then I press list item number 2
And I wait
Then I see "Amey Reference"
Then I press view with id "btnStartJob"
And I wait
If I see "Warning" then press "Okay" else I should see "Job Detail"
```

Comment: If you want to if/else in step, the first thing you should created/customize the function by Ruby then make sure you must re-build the calabash again.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a proper think about this and realised I could just do a "Given" here. Below is an example:

```
Given that I see "Wrong Device Detected!"
Then I press "Yes"
```

And in my calabash steps I have defined this step:

```
Given /^that I see "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text|
    query("* text:'#{text}'")[0]
end
```

Comment: Its also OK for some easy case. 
In generally , we should customize the current calabash and of course we must re-build the calabash again ( by rake...)